# How to stop button from moving when navar collapse toggle is clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to have my navbar set up like this:
[collapse] navbar icon         links         sign in button

I have this set up fine. The problem is that when the navbar collapse toggle is clicked, it moves the sign in button under the dropdown with the links. How do I keep the sign in button above that dropdown so the order is collapse toggle in top left, dropdown links, sign in button in top right

[image: normal navbar]
[image: normal collapse]
[image: when expanded, it moves the sign in button]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>est</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/website/test.png') }}" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50">
                    test
                </a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" style="width: 30vw;">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                              test
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>






        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script/index.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

using bootstrap v5.3.0-alpha1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .navbar .btn-group {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 12px;
  }
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .navbar .btn-group {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>est</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/website/test.png') }}" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50"> test
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" style="width: 30vw;">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            test
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script/index.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```